# C# Windows Form post status update on Twitter

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, twitter, status

C# Windows Form post status update on Twitter

I have tried all the solutions I can find and pieced together the following code which always gives a 401 authorisation error.

When I set up a twitter application in twitter it asked for a callback url, I am developing this on my local machine and need to use windows forms so the tweets can get the data from my local database. I only want to tweet from my own account but get data from my database to insert into the tweets when I add new items.

I have tried changing the encoding to UTF8 (left previous string definitions commented out to show where), after reading this could be a problem somewhere.

I do not know if there is something wrong with the authorisation as I have all the required keys or if it is to do with the callback url, and if so what can I use for a windows form client with no website.

If I paste the CURL from the dev.twitter site into my browser I get "Bad Authentication data" when using https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json (it defaults to 1 and gives a message saying this has been deprecated). The website I have entered for callback url is mine, but I do not know if there needs to be code there for this test to function.

Any help would be appreciated I have been trying to resolve this for a week now.

```
public static void anotherTweet(string status)
{
    //GS - Get the oAuth params
    //string status = status;
    string postBody = "status=" + 
        Uri.EscapeDataString(status);

    string oauth_consumer_key = "xxx";
    //string oauth_nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(
        //new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(
           // DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()));
    string oauth_nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()));    
    string oauth_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1";
    string oauth_token =
        "xxx";
    string oauth_version = "1.0";
    TimeSpan ts = DateTime.UtcNow - 
        new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    string oauth_timestamp = 
        Convert.ToInt64(ts.TotalSeconds).ToString();

    //string oauth_version = "1.0";

    //GS - When building the signature string the params
    //must be in alphabetical order. I can't be bothered
    //with that, get SortedDictionary to do it's thing
    SortedDictionary<string, string> sd = 
        new SortedDictionary<string, string>();

    sd.Add("status", status);
    sd.Add("oauth_version", oauth_version);
    sd.Add("oauth_consumer_key", oauth_consumer_key);
    sd.Add("oauth_nonce", oauth_nonce);
    sd.Add("oauth_signature_method", oauth_signature_method);
    sd.Add("oauth_timestamp", oauth_timestamp);
    sd.Add("oauth_token", oauth_token);

    //GS - Build the signature string
    string baseString = String.Empty;
    baseString += "POST" + "&";

    baseString += Uri.EscapeDataString(
        "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json") 
        + "&";

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string,string> entry in sd)
    {
        baseString += Uri.EscapeDataString(entry.Key + 
            "=" + entry.Value + "&");
    }

    //GS - Remove the trailing ambersand char, remember 
    //it's been urlEncoded so you have to remove the 
    //last 3 chars - %26
    baseString = 
        baseString.Substring(0, baseString.Length - 3);

    //GS - Build the signing key
    string consumerSecret =
        "xxx";

    string oauth_token_secret =
        "xxx";

    string signingKey = 
        Uri.EscapeDataString(consumerSecret) + "&" + 
        Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token_secret);

    //GS - Sign the request
    HMACSHA1 hasher = new HMACSHA1(
        new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(signingKey));

    //string signatureString = Convert.ToBase64String(
        //hasher.ComputeHash(
       // new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(baseString)));

    string signatureString = Convert.ToBase64String(
        hasher.ComputeHash(
    System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(baseString)));


    //GS - Tell Twitter we don't do the 100 continue thing
    ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

    //GS - Instantiate a web request and populate the 
    //authorization header
    HttpWebRequest hwr = 
        (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
        @"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json");

    string authorizationHeaderParams = String.Empty;
    authorizationHeaderParams += "OAuth ";
    authorizationHeaderParams += "oauth_nonce=" + "\"" + 
        Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_nonce) + "\",";

    authorizationHeaderParams += 
        "oauth_signature_method=" + "\"" + 
        Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature_method) + 
        "\",";

    authorizationHeaderParams += "oauth_timestamp=" + "\"" + 
        Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_timestamp) + "\",";

    authorizationHeaderParams += "oauth_consumer_key=" 
        + "\"" + Uri.EscapeDataString(
        oauth_consumer_key) + "\",";

    authorizationHeaderParams += "oauth_token=" + "\"" + 
        Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token) + "\",";

    authorizationHeaderParams += "oauth_signature=" + "\"" 
        + Uri.EscapeDataString(signatureString) + "\",";

    //authorizationHeaderParams += "oauth_version=" + "\"" + 
        //Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_version) + "\"";

    hwr.Headers.Add(
        "Authorization", authorizationHeaderParams);

    //GS - POST off the request
    hwr.Method = "POST";
    hwr.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    Stream stream = hwr.GetRequestStream();
    //byte[] bodyBytes = 
        //new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(postBody);
    byte[] bodyBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postBody);    
    stream.Write(bodyBytes, 0, bodyBytes.Length);
    stream.Flush();
    stream.Close();

    //GS - Allow us a reasonable timeout in case
    //Twitter's busy
    hwr.Timeout = 3 * 60 * 1000;

    try 
    { 
        HttpWebResponse rsp = hwr.GetResponse() 
            as HttpWebResponse;
        //GS - Do something with the return here...
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: OAUTH can be difficult to troubleshoot.  Rather than rolling your own OAuth code, I would strongly recommend using one of the established OAuth libraries out there.  This will let you focus on your application instead of debugging OAuth.  I would look into DotNetOpenAuth at http://dotnetopenauth.net/

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to post from your account, you can simply create a Token on dev.twitter.com.
You can then use the credentials of your new application directly within your code.

Like the previous comment I would recommend to either use an OAuth or Twitter library.